# I am getting empty list while I am trying to access the list in other class

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing an app with the help of spoonacular API. I want to access the `reciepeList` list variable in the main.dart so that I can implement it in the UI. But while doing that its giving me an empty list. But within the function its running properly.
This is my services.dart:-

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:spponacular/reciepe.dart';
class GetRecipies{
final dynamic api='9c9a158fced340a1873d5988704968c2';
List<Reciepes>reciepeList=[];
   Future getReciepe() async{
    try{
      // make the request
      Response response = await get(Uri.parse('https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/findByNutrients?apiKey=$api&minCalories=50&maxCalories=700&number=7'));
      List data = jsonDecode(response.body);  
      reciepeList=data.map((e) {
        return Reciepes(name:"${e['title']}", image: "${e['image']}", calories: "${e['calories']}", carbs: "${e['carbs']}", fat: "${e['fat']}", protein: "${e['protein']}");}).toList();
        print(reciepeList[0].name);
        print(reciepeList);             
}
    catch (e) {
      print(e);      
     }  
     
  } 
          
  }
```

If I try to print the `reciepieList` within the function I am getting the right output.
But if I try to access the list through an object in the main.dart the list is empty. The output of the `recipieList` length is showing 0. How to fix this?? And why am I getting this problem?
This is my main.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:spponacular/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Home(),
  ));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    GetRecipies obj=GetRecipies();
    print(obj.reciepeList.length);

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
        title: Text('Recipes'),
        
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context,index){
            return Container(


            );

        }),
      
            );
          
        
      
    
  }
}
```

Comment: The [discussion for your earlier, deleted question](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237077/discussion-between-divya-and-rob) already told you what was wrong: you're calling an asynchronous function and not waiting for its `Future` to complete.  I suggest reading [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/)

Comment: Actually that solution is not working for me, So I made it as a single class. So that I am not accessing anyhting. But now since I am using listview nothing is showing.

Comment: Read about and use FutureBuilder. Then, make the call to the API on the future: parameter from FutureBuilder

Comment: I will definitely do that  Thank you so much for both of you.